# SQL Sever 2019 on Server Management Studio 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the below query but doesn't seems to be working as it is showing Invalid object name 'P'

> Write a query to display profile id, full name,  phone, email id, city
> , house id, move_in_date , move_out date, rent, total number of
> referrals made,  latest employer and the occupational category of all
> the tenants living in Bangalore or Pune in the time period of jan 2015
> to jan 2016 sorted by their rent in descending order

I have created the below query but doesn't seems to be working as it is showing Invalid object name 'P'. Please help.

```
With P as
(
select profile_id, first_name+ ' '+ last_name as Full_Name, phone, email_id, city
from Profiles$ 
where city in ('Bangalore','Pune')),
TH as (
select profile_id, house_id, move_in_date, move_out_date, rent
from Tenancy_History
where move_in_date >= '2015-01-01' AND move_in_Date<= '2016-01-31'),
ES as (
select profile_id, latest_employer, occupational_category
from Employment_Details$),
R as (
select profile_id, sum(referral_valid) as "Total Referral"
from Referral$
group by profile_id)


select P.profile_id, P.Full_Name, P.phone, P.email_id, P.city, TH.house_id, TH.move_in_date, TH.move_out_date, TH.rent, R.Total Referral, ES.latest_employer, ES.occupational_category
from P
inner join TH on 
P.profile_id=TH.profile_id
inner join ES on
P.profile_id=ES.profile_id
inner join R on
P.profile_id=R.profile_id
```

Comment: from the Query that you posted, I don't see any error other than `Total Referral` . You need to enclose it with bracket `[Total Referral]`

Comment: Did you execute the entire query? Seems like you might have only selected the second half of the query starting with `select P.profile_id, ...`

Answer (score 0):

no need to use a common table expression

```
select   P.profile_id
      ,  P.Full_Name
      ,  P.phone
      ,  P.email_id
      ,  P.city
      ,  TH.house_id
      ,  TH.move_in_date
      ,  TH.move_out_date
      ,  TH.rent
      ,  sum (R.referral_valid) as [Total Referral]
      ,  ES.latest_employer
      ,  ES.occupational_category
from     Profiles$            P
join     Tenancy_History      TH on P.profile_id=TH.profile_id
join     Employment_Details$  ES on P.profile_id=ES.profile_id
join     Referral$            R  on P.profile_id=R.profile_id
where    city in ('Bangalore','Pune')
  and    TH.move_in_date >= '2015-01-01' 
  AND    TH.move_in_Date <= '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY P.profile_id
    ,    P.Full_Name
    ,    P.phone
    ,    P.email_id
    ,    P.city
    ,    TH.house_id
    ,    TH.move_in_date
    ,    TH.move_out_date
    ,    TH.rent
    ,    ES.latest_employer
    ,    ES.occupational_category
```